# How to insert into an table from a function with returns a type as object in plsql

Tags: oracle, types, plsql

I have created a type as object which goes like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE rec_alloc_rate is record (
cu_alloc_rate NUMBER(30,10),
au_alloc_rate NUMBER(30,10)
);
```

I then have created a function which is like

```
create or replace function fn_get_x(num1 number)
return rec_alloc_rate is
var1 number;
var2 number;
begin

select 1 num1,2 num2 into var1, var2 from dual;
return rec_alloc_rate(var1,var2);


end;
```

Now I cannot do an insert.

```
create table test_1
(num1 number,
num2 number);

insert into test_1
  (num1, num2)
  select fn_get_x(1) from dual;
```

Can you please help.

Comment: `Now I cannot do an insert` why? do you get any error?

Comment: Yes i do. It says not enough values.

Comment: The type declaration and what you're using in the function aren't consistent; and the type should be an `object` not a `record`, no? But you must be using different things to be able to get to the error you are seeing. Your function returns an object; the table has two scalar columns, so naturally they don't match. Maybe you should explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear what you're trying to do, but if you want to insert object attributes into individual scalar columns in a table you'd need to extract them:

```
insert into test_1 (num1, num2)
select fn_get_x(1).cu_alloc_rate, fn_get_x(1).au_alloc_rate
from dual;
```

But that is likely to call the function twice as it isn't deterministic, so you could avoid that by using a subquery:

```
insert into test_1 (num1, num2)
select t.x.cu_alloc_rate, t.x.au_alloc_rate
from (select fn_get_x(1) as x from dual) t;
```

Note that you have to fully qualify the value with the table and column aliases; just `x.cu_alloc_rate` would not be recognised, you have to specify `t.x.cu_alloc_rate`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8383/2).